# iCloud Sync - Core Data Duplicate Entries (Desperate Help)

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, icloud, duplicates

I've been having this bug for several weeks already. I searched on many forums every reply on duplicates and I implemented some of the normal approaches and still it doesn't work properly.

So to give you some context I'm working on a recipe application that scraps html recipes from the web and stores it in core data, simple right? Well when the client asked adding support for iCloud Sync I though it was going to be easy specially working on iOS 7 only which solves most of the problems for you.

The problems arises when the app populates initial data in the application. I have two related entities called MainCategory[e1] and Category[e2], there is one to many relationship between them (e1 <->>> e2).

The first the app starts it will create 5 Main Categories and for each Main Category it will add 5 Categories

```
+ (BOOL)initialLoad
{

    DLog(@"Initial Load");

    //Create main and sub categories to database
    NSDictionary * categoriesDic = @{
                                     CAT_MEAL_TYPE: @[C_STARTER,C_MAINS,C_DESSERT,C_SOUPS,C_SALAD],
                                     CAT_INGREDIENT: @[C_BEEF,C_CHICKEN,C_PASTA,C_SALMON,C_CHOCOLATE],
                                     CAT_CUISINE : @[C_CHINESE,C_FRENCH,C_INDIAN,C_ITALIAN,C_MOROCCAN],
                                     CAT_SEASON : @[C_CHRISTMAS,C_SUNDAY_ROAST,C_DINNER,C_BBQ,C_NIBBLES],
                                     CAT_DIET : @[C_WHEATFREE,C_VEGETARIAN,C_LOW_FAT,C_LOW_GI,C_DAIRY_FREE]
                                     };

    NSArray * mainCategoryKeys = @[CAT_MEAL_TYPE,CAT_INGREDIENT,CAT_CUISINE,CAT_SEASON,CAT_DIET];


    for(NSString * eachMainCategoryName in mainCategoryKeys)
    {
        //Create Main category
       MainCategory *  eachMainCategory = [MainCategory mainCategoryWithName:eachMainCategoryName];

        NSArray * subCategories = [categoriesDic objectForKey:eachMainCategoryName];

        //Create Sub categories and adds them to main category
        for(NSString * eachCategoryName in subCategories)
        {
           /*Category got renamed to zCategory given it's a reserver name in the framework and 
            can not be used */
           zCategory * eachCategory = [zCategory categoryWithName:eachCategoryName];
            [eachMainCategory addCategoriesObject:eachCategory];
        }
    }

    [((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) saveContext];

    return TRUE;

}`
```

Then after saving the context all this initial data will sync with the database in iCloud, so far so good. The problem comes when on the second device it runs the same initialLoad code and gets sync once again. The result is getting double MainCategories and Categories as many of you know this problem.

After reading several threads about how to remove them I used the dateCreated approach where you add a NSDate property to each entity so every time you create one instance it will have a timestamp to track which one is older and which one is newer. Then I simply add an observer from NSNotificationCenter checking the iCloud import notification **NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification** and runs a timerCheck that after 5 seconds will execute on the mainThread a clean duplicates method.

```
- (void)checkTimer{


    if(self.cleanTimer)
    {
        [self.cleanTimer invalidate];
        self.cleanTimer = nil;
    }//schedule timer to clean iCloud duplicates of database
    self.cleanTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(cleanDuplicates:) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE];
} 

- (void)cleanDuplicates:(NSTimer*)timer{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cleanCron) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];}
```

I'm invalidating the timer every time checkTimer method gets call in order to restart it again because you normally get several **NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification** when content gets updated/inserted/deleted, this way I know it will run once after all the notifications have gone through.

btw cleanCron just calls a class method cleanDuplicates

```
- (void)cleanCron
{
    [CTFetchCoreData cleanDuplicates];
}`
```

Here is where the non magic happens, I get all the MainCategories which will be 10 given they have been duplicated and order them with the oldest ones at the beginning, then it iterates and save them in an dictionary with their name as the key so whenever it finds another MainCategory with the same name it just deletes it. Btw in the relationship e1<->>e2 there is a cascade delete rule so every time you delete a MainCategory item it deletes all the related Categories with it so there shouldn't be a problem.

```
+ (BOOL)cleanDuplicates
{

    @synchronized(self){

        //Fetch mainCategories from coreData 
        NSArray * mainCategories = [CTFetchCoreData fetchAllMainCategories];

        // Clean duplicate Main Categories
        NSMutableDictionary * uniqueMainCatDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        // Sorts the array with the oldest dateCreated one
        mainCategories  = [mainCategories  sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MainCategory* obj1,MainCategory * obj2) {
            if(obj1.dateCreated == nil || obj2.dateCreated == nil)
            {
                DLog(@"ERROR Date Created");
            }

            return [obj1.dateCreated compare:obj2.dateCreated];
        }];

        // if there are more than five MainCategories it procedes the clenaup
        if(mainCategories.count > 5)
        {
            for(MainCategory* eachMainCat in mainCategories)
            {
                MainCategory * originalMainCat = [uniqueMainCatDic objectForKey:eachMainCat.name];

                if( originalMainCat == nil)
                {
                    DLog(@"-> %@ = %@",eachMainCat.name, eachMainCat.dateCreated);
                    [uniqueMainCatDic setObject:eachMainCat forKey:eachMainCat.name];

                }else{

                    // Clean duplicate Categories
                    [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:eachMainCat];
                    DLog(@"x %@ = %@",eachMainCat.name, eachMainCat.dateCreated);

                }
            }
            DLog(@"Cleaning Main Categories");

        }        
    }

    [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] saveContext];



    return TRUE;
}
```

It turns out that after I run it on the second device I will get this output :

```
Sesame[4145:60b]   -> Cuisine = 2014-02-06 16:15:38 +0000 
Sesame[4145:60b]   -> Meal = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   x Meal = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   -> Ingredients = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   x Ingredients = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   x Cuisine = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   x Cuisine = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   -> Occasion = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   -> Diet = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
Sesame[4145:60b]   x Diet = 2014-02-06 17:15:54 +0000
```

which means that the same MainCategories are getting deleted, they have the same timestamp! I'm wondering how iCloud gets the information merged.

Please if you know a better approach to clean duplicated apart from the dateCreated property please tell me because I've tried it a lot without luck, there should be a better approach.

Thanks in advance!

1. Update :

Finally I've managed to solve my problem after all, crazy as it sounds I was getting duplicate instances from iCloud! that's what the dates were the same. I just added an if to check if both dates are the same then don't delete the MainCategory, and so next time you open your app Core Data will refix the merge and update the database with the correct instances and different date values as it was supposed to be.

Comment: This is not something I have had to deal with so I can't give you a solution but the following link discusses your problem and a solution in some detail (with code). The company seem to have taken a similar approach to yourself but have succeeded: http://cutecoder.org/programming/seeding-icloud-core-data/

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I will check the article and let you know! Hope Apple address this issue properly

Comment: Hi, I just posted some sample apps that check iCloud first to see if a file exists already before loading seed data - it may give you some pointers as to how to prevent your app from loading the categories on the second device.  Bear in mind that the user should have both devices set to use iCloud for this to work. BTW you also need to fix up any relationships you are using that may be associated with the deleted categories. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code, though I would recommend using UUIDs instead of dates for ordering your duplicates. But that is unlikely to be related to what you are seeing.

To be honest, it looks to me that Core Data is really messing things up. (Eg It also seems there are 3 Cuisine categories.)

I experienced this type of issue when working with Core Data sync if I tried to delete the cloud data files, and didn't give it time to thoroughly remove the files from all devices. You end up with old transaction logs in there, which trigger extra objects to be inserted.

Core Data also tries to handle all merging on its own. How that happens is anyone's guess.

Core Data + iCloud is a bit unusual in that it is one of the only sync frameworks which has no concept of global identity. There are actually good reasons for Apple not doing it, which are too subtle to discuss here, but it does make it difficult for developers. Deduping post-merge is an ugly solution IMO. Your store has to become invalid before it can become valid again.

I much prefer the approach of frameworks like Wasabi Sync, TICDS, and Ensembles, which all have a concept of global identity and do not require deduping as a result.

(Disclosure: I founded and develop the Ensembles framework)

Comment: Thanks Drew for your insights. Indeed Apple has to keep on working harder on iCloud+CoreData Sync, it odd and does unexpected things. Finally I've managed to solve my problem after all, crazy as it sounds I was getting duplicate instances! that's what the dates were the same. I just added an if to check if both dates are the same then don't delete it, and so next time you open your app Core Data will update the database with the correct instances and different date values.

Answer (score 0):

Also avoid using this

```
NSMutableDictionary * uniqueMainCatDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

rather use

```
NSMutableDictionary * uniqueMainCatDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

I think your weirdness of duplicates may go away if you always alloc the mutable dictionary.  It took me weeks to figure this out - not sure if its a bug.

Comment: Hey Duncan, that seems strange indeed. Given that nowadays all projects are ARC enabled both methods should return a retained object